# Implement F# libraries for consumption by TypeScript/Javascript?

Tags: f#, typescript, websharper, funscript

I know there are a number of projects which can compile F# to JavaScript.
Does any of these projects support this use case:

- developing an application in TypeScript
- but writing part of the application in F#, as a library
- consuming this F# library from the main TypeScript application, optimally in a type-safe way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSharper produces `d.ts` files for the compiled JS files. You can read about this in the [relevant section of the documentation](http://www.websharper.com/docs/ts-output). However this feature is still experimental and uses an older version of TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks, that looks interesting! I think `t.ds` files generated for 1.4 should also be compatible with newer TypeScript versions.

Answer (score 1):

There is [FunScript](http://funscript.info/) (https://github.com/ZachBray/FunScript) but it does not seem to be widespread, so it may take you more time than the benefits are.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, it looks like FunScript is not designed for this use case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19260214/79795

Comment: I see. Well, from what I know about transcompilation, I don't think you will find anything useful because results of transcompilations are not typically human-friendly. I would just convert F# code to JS by a tool and I would write some TypeScript code that uses the JS code as an external module (you can generate [a TypeScript definition file](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Writing%20Definition%20%28.d.ts%29%20Files) for the JS code though to get type control). I would definitely not try to adjust the generated JS code.